# How to make a keras model take a (None,) tensor as Input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am using the tf.keras API and I want my Model to take input with shape `(None,)`,  `None` is batch_size.

The `shape` of keras.layers.Input() doesn't include batch_size, so I think it can't be used.

Is there a way to achieve my goal? I prefer a solution without `tf.placeholder` since it is deprecated

By the way, my model is a sentence embedding model, so I want the input is something like ['How are you.','Good morning.']

======================
Update:

Currently, I can create an input layer with `layers.Input(dtype=tf.string,shape=1)`, but this need my input to be something like `[['How are you.'],['Good morning.']]`. I want my input to have only one dimension.

Comment: Inputs to a Keras model always have a batch dimension, so it makes no sense to want to remove this dimension, the framework does not support that.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am not trying to remove batch dimension, what I want is to make my input a simple string.

Comment: A batch of strings makes sense, a single string would not be a good input (as it misses the batch dimension).

Comment: Yes, what I mean is a batch of strings when training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `tf.keras.layers.Input(dtype=tf.string, shape=())`?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want, you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to set a specific batch size, `tf.keras.Input()` does actually include a `batch_size` parameter. But the batch size is presumed to be `None` by default, so you shouldn't even need to change anything.

Now, it seems like what you actually want is to be able to provide samples (sentences) of variable length. Good news! The `tf.keras.layers.Embedding` layer allows you to do this, although you'll have to generate an encoding for your sentences first. The Tensorflow website has a good [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings) on the process.

Comment: This is not what I want, I have updated my question to make it more clear.